# How to implement MVP using Vaadin CDI and Navigator?

Tags: java, vaadin, cdi, mvp

I would like to implement the MVP pattern in my web application using Vaadin. I am using the Vaadin Navigator and the CDIViewProvider, something like so:

```
//MyUI.java
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Inject
    CDIViewProvider viewProvider;

    Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        //UI setup
        navigator = new Navigator(this, someContainer);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
        getNavigator().navigateTo("myView");
    }
}

//MyViewImpl.java
@CDIView("myView")
public class MyViewImpl extends VerticalLayout implements com.vaadin.navigator.View, MyView {
    // ...
```

To my understanding the view provider instantiates an object of MyViewImpl which is ViewScoped, i.e. it gets created/destroyed as the user navigates to/out of this view. Next I need to think about where to instantiate the presenter of this view. I thought about making it SessionScoped and inject it to the view:

```
// ... continue MyViewImpl.java

@Inject 
private MyViewListener presenter;

// in some of the MyViewImpl methods we can do stuff like presenter.buttonClicked();
}

//MyViewPresenter.java
@SessionScoped
public class MyViewPresenter implements MyView.MyViewListener {

    MyView view; //how can the presenter obtain the view here ?

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() 
    @Override
    public void buttonClicked() {
        view.displaySomething();
    }
}

//MyView.java
public interface MyView {
    public interface MyViewListener {     
        public void buttonClicked();
    }

    public void displaySomething();
}
```

As I already pointed out in the comment behind the presenters reference to the view I do not know how the presenter can get a hold of the view instance (which is created by the view provider). Does it even make sense to have the presenter be SessionScoped, while the views get created/destroyed whenever the view changes ? An alternative way would be that the view does not have a reference to the presenter, but that the presenter adds itself as the listener to the view. However in this case I again do not know where to instantiate the presenter and how to get a reference to the current view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to inject the view, use a view setter in presenter instead and call it from view's `@PostConstruct`:

```
@Dependent
class MyPresenter {

    private MyView view;

    public void setView(MyView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}

public interface MyView {
}

@CDIView("my-view")
public class MyViewImpl extends VerticalLayout implements View, MyView {

    @Inject
    private MyPresenter presenter;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        presenter.setView(this);
    }
}
```

I think that creation order is the confusing issue here. In a way views have higher priority as they are created by Vaadin when you call `getNavigator().navigateTo("my-view")`. Presenter is instantiated by the view by CDI (even though it supervises the view) and should have `@Dependent` scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that a view gets the presenter injected and **vice versa**. So one strategy for the approach you have above is making the `Presenter` `@Dependent` scoped and put `@Inject` `MyViewPresenter` `presenter` in the view and `@Inject` `MyView` `view` into the presenter. `@Dependent` makes them reside in the same scope which is quite probably what you want to achieve

Comment: does this not give me a circular dependency ?

Comment: the weld implementation I am using thinks otherwise (?) org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001443: Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies

Comment: I think it is mouch cleaner when the View does not have direct dependency on specific presenter, but instead listeners can register themselves to listen to view events and view notifies those when something happens. Thus registered presenter then decides how to react on given event (or whether react at all).

Comment: I agree, but I do not know how to achieve this when using the Navigator.

Comment: I don't agree that using events is cleaner - code is easy to read and reason about when view and presenter are integrated at API level. Events don't create a nice clear contract like view interface does, tracking them and their changes is harder.