# Howto add and navigate between pages in Vaadin framework

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin

I'd like to add a new page with Vaadin like:

```
localhost:8080/register
```

I have my second page, done with Vaadin designer, but I don't know how implement this .java file in my first one.

Does anyone know?

Comment: So is your Vaadin version 8?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far too broad to have a simple answer (means not coding it for you). I suggest that you take look at `Navigator` how this could be achieved.

With Vaadin `Navigator` you define `Views` that can the be loaded as a part of your `UI` or replace `UI`s whole contents.

You seem to develop in `Java EE` environment so `@CDIUi` & `@CDIView` & `@CDIViewProvider` are also good point to start further research.

See [example](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator.html)

If you feel ready you can also start right away with `CDI`, see [How to implement MVP using Vaadin CDI and Navigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184406/how-to-implement-mvp-using-vaadin-cdi-and-navigator)

Comment: OK, so if I understand well, the navigator will be the main class, and i'll call each other class from this one ?

Comment: @AntoineGaia Please see the example behind the link. Navigator is not the 'main class' not sure what you mean by that. Navigator is just an object - not ui object - that manages `navigateTo(page)` requests so that it  replaces some containercomponets contents with the contents of the requested page.